# Group rows and subtract in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have an array containing made up from two lists as shown below:

```
([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[29,34,70,21,56,43,89,11,90,42,87])
```

Eventually I want to be able to find the difference between the values with an index of 1 i.e. 29, 34 and 70. And likewise for every other index shown.

I have turned this into a dataframe but this has been reasonably pointless - I was looking to work with pandas and have found this easier before; but I now just have the option of the same data in a different format.

The dataframe I produced used this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': index, 'Value': value})
```

I also tried using split to separate the rows as a starting point before subtraction but this was unsuccessful as the 1 index makes up three rows not two so there are not regular intervals.

So the desired result would look something like this:

```
([1,1,2,3,4,5],[5,36,35,46,79,35])
```

in any form of dataframe, array, list etc...

Any help with this/steps towards this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post what the disered result would look like?

Comment: @P.Pinho , hopefully this will help clarify?

Comment: Check out my answer, I presented it in `dataframe` format, I believe it is easier to manage this way, but if you want, you can create a `tupple` containing those two lists easily from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index' :[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
                   'Values':[29,34,70,21,56,43,89,11,90,42,87]})
df.sort_values('Index', ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

```
  Index Values
0     1     29
1     1     34
2     1     70
3     2     21
4     2     56
5     3     43
6     3     89
7     4     11
8     4     90
9     5     42
10    5     87
```

Creating a new column with the differencies applied by groups of indexes:

```py
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('Index').diff()
```

Output:

```
  Index Values  Diff
0     1     29   NaN
1     1     34   5.0
2     1     70  36.0
3     2     21   NaN
4     2     56  35.0
5     3     43   NaN
6     3     89  46.0
7     4     11   NaN
8     4     90  79.0
9     5     42   NaN
10    5     87  45.0
```

Dropping `NaN` rows:

```py
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
df

  Index Values   Diff
1     1     34    5.0
2     1     70   36.0
4     2     56   35.0
6     3     89   46.0
8     4     90   79.0
10    5     87   45.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

```
data = ([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[29,34,70,21,56,43,89,11,90,42,87])
```

We can create a `pandas.Series` with the appropriate values and index, then group by the index, apply the `.diff` and then drop missing values:

```
s = pd.Series(data[1], index=data[0]).groupby(level=0).diff().dropna()
```

This gives us:

```
1     5.0
1    36.0
2    35.0
3    46.0
4    79.0
5    45.0
dtype: float64
```

Then create a 2-tuple of the index and values converted to lists:

```
out = (s.index.to_list(), s.to_list())
```

And you end up with:

```
([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5.0, 36.0, 35.0, 46.0, 79.0, 45.0])
```